# Call Javascript method that is tied to user control from aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, custom-controls

So I have a custom asp.net control that has javascript. I want to be able to call ResetTimeout method on the control that is on the custom control from the page that the custom control is on.

Here is an example of what my code looks like

```
    **TestControl.CS**
```

---

```
 [CLSCompliant(true)]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:TestControl runat=server></{0}:TestControl >")]
    public class TestControl : WebControl, INamingContainer, IScriptControl, ICallbackEventHandler
    {

    }
```

---

```
  **TestControl.JS**

 // Timout Handler -- builds or resets the timeouts
 ResetTimeout: function () {
    this.HideControl();
    this.StartTimers();
},
```

---

```
 **TestPage.ASPX**


<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            ($("#<%=Test.ClientID%>").ResetTimeout());
        }
    </script>

 <cc1:TestControl id="Test" runat="server"> </TestControl>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this: `($("#<%=Test.ClientID%>").ResetTimeout());` to `$find("<%= Test.ClientID %>").ResetTimeout();`

Comment: What is the diff between $find() and $() ?

Comment: $find is a shortcut for `Sys.Application.findComponent` (part of MicrosoftAjax library) whereas $ is a shortcut for jQuery. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2007/02/19/sysk-290-asp-net-ajax-get-vs-find.aspx

Comment: @MicahArmantrout I believe this links also will be useful for you: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/ASPNETAJAXControlDevelopment.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx

Comment: Great Article I could not find alot talking about this kinda stuff

Comment: Does the fact that this control is on a master and I want to call it from a child page make a difference ? I got my test app to work but not my Application

Comment: I believe that doesn't matter. Check browser's script console for error messages

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22478/discussion-between-micah-armantrout-and-yuriy-rozhovetskiy)